# Timer class not restarting timer - Android

Tags: java, android, timer

I have a trivia game of 10 questions with a 10 second timer for each question.  When the timer runs out, the question changes to the next but the timer never restarts.  It stays at 0.  I cannot seem to find where in code that keeps the timer from restarting when the next question is displayed.

Also, code structure suggestions is appreciated!

Thank you in advance.

QuestionView.java

```
public class QuestionView extends Activity  {

    int correctAnswers = 0;
    int wrongAnswers = 0;
    int answer = 0;
    int i = 0;

    long score = 0;

    long startTime = 10000;
    long interval = 1000;
    long timeElapsed;

    boolean timerHasStarted = false;

    String category;

    Button answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4;
    TextView question, timer, timeElapsedView;

    ArrayList<Question> queries;
    Timer cdTimer;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.questionviewmain);

        answer1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.answer1);
        answer2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.answer2);
        answer3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.answer3);
        answer4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.answer4);

        question = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.question);

        category = getIntent().getStringExtra("category");
        queries = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("queries");

        timer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timer);
        timeElapsedView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timeElapsedView);

        cdTimer = new Timer(startTime, interval);

              loadQuestion();
    }

    public void loadQuestion() {
        if(i == 9) {
            endQuiz();
        } else {
            if(!timerHasStarted) {
                cdTimer.start();
                timerHasStarted = true;
            } else {
                cdTimer.cancel();
                timerHasStarted = false;
            }

            answer = queries.get(i).getCorrectAnswer();
            question.setText(queries.get(i).getQuery());

            answer1.setText(queries.get(i).getA1());
            answer2.setText(queries.get(i).getA2());
            answer3.setText(queries.get(i).getA3());
            answer4.setText(queries.get(i).getA4());

            answer1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    queries.get(i).setSelectedAnswer(0);
                    if(answer == 0) {
                        correctAnswers++;
                        nextQuestion();
                    } else {
                        wrongAnswers++;
                        nextQuestion();
                    }
                }
            });

            //Same code for button 1 for buttons 2 through 4.
        } 
    }

    public void nextQuestion() {
        score = score + ((startTime / 100) - timeElapsed);
        i++;
        loadQuestion();
    }

    public class Timer extends CountDownTimer {

        public Timer(long startTime, long interval) {
            super(startTime, interval);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            if(i == 9) {
                cdTimer.cancel();
            } else {
                wrongAnswers++;
                nextQuestion();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            timer.setText("Time remaining: " + (millisUntilFinished / 100));
            timeElapsed = 100 - ((startTime - millisUntilFinished) / 100);
            timeElapsedView.setText("Points remaining: " + timeElapsed);
        }
    }

    public void endQuiz() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(QuestionView.this, Results.class);
        intent.putExtra("correctAnswers", correctAnswers);
        intent.putExtra("wrongAnswers", wrongAnswers);
        intent.putExtra("score", score);
        intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("queries", queries);
        intent.putExtra("category", category);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: just make `timerHasStarted=false`  when `CountDownTimer` finish  inside `onFinish()`

Comment: In your ``loadQuestion`` you cancel the timer at least if it has been started. You probably don't want to do that but start it instead. You could try adding line ``timerHasStarted = false`` to ``onFinish()`` method.

Comment: yeah, why are you even cancelling the timer, anyway ?

Comment: Thank you @harism.  All I had to do was change the ````else```` statement in ````loadQuestion()```` to start instead of cancel and its working.  As for why I was cancelling it - its because I made this whole class by combining around 5 examples I found on the internet and I just didn't integrate it perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

try the following and see if it helps. furthermore, calling `cancel()` inside the timer's own `onFinish()` method is unneeded since the timer would have already been cancelled to reach that method.

```
public void loadQuestion() {
        if(i == 9) {
            endQuiz();
        } else {
            cdTimer.start(); //start timer here
            answer = queries.get(i).getCorrectAnswer();
            question.setText(queries.get(i).getQuery());

            answer1.setText(queries.get(i).getA1());
            answer2.setText(queries.get(i).getA2());
            answer3.setText(queries.get(i).getA3());
            answer4.setText(queries.get(i).getA4());

            answer1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                    cdTimer.cancel(); // end it when clicked.
                    queries.get(i).setSelectedAnswer(0);
                    if(answer == 0) {
                        correctAnswers++;
                        nextQuestion();
                    } else {
                        wrongAnswers++;
                        nextQuestion();
                    }
                }
            });

            //Same code for button 1 for buttons 2 through 4.
        } 
    }
```